# Batch remove comments from PDF files

Tags: pdf, batch, ghostscript

How can I easily remove all comments and annotations (added with Foxit Reader) from all the PDFs in a folder?

Comment: is it a valid assumption to think you want only suggestions for free (as in beer) or for Free (as in liberty) solutions?

Comment: @pipitas I am interested in any kind of solution.

Answer (score 12):

I just came across this problem, and none of the answers given here worked for me.  What *did* work was the `rewritepdf` tool from the Ubuntu package `libcam-pdf-perl`:

```
rewritepdf -C in.pdf out.pdf
```

Wrapping this into a little scripting to remove annotations from all pdf files in a directory is now easy:

```
for i in *.pdf; do rewritepdf -C '$i' '$i'.new; done
```

As usual, you can install `libcam-pdf-perl` via the Software Center or using `sudo apt install libcam-pdf-perl`

Comment: It worked fine.:) Some help: The Ubuntu (i.e., debian) package is here https://packages.debian.org/sid/perl/libcam-pdf-perl  Dependences are automatically installed using the "Ubuntu software center". (Oh, and watch out with the capital "-C". I first ran "-c" and nothing happened, even no error was output.)

Comment: The single quote apparently needs to be replaced by double quotes, otherwise literal $i is passed as a filename to the command (I'm a Windows user and installed WSL to try this).

Answer (score 5):

Providing you're on a Unix system:

```
cd <directory containing PDFs>
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec perl -pi -e 's:/Annots \[[^]]+\]::g' {} +
```

This is a hack that removes all `/Annots` commands from the PDF (the commands that draws the annotations). It leaves the annotation objects there (you can open the PDF with a text editor and search for them), they're just not drawn.

Comment: Can you explain the RE? What does [^]]+ match

Comment: @jftuga, `s:` (substitute) `/Annots \[` (the text "`/Annots [`") `[^]]+` (one or more instances of any character besides "`]`") `\]` (the literal character "`]`") `::` (replace anything matching the former with nothing) `g` (replace multiple times per line if necessary).

Comment: One potentially confusing part of the regex is that a literal `]` normally has to be escaped, but not right after a `^` negation.

Comment: This also removes internal document links (as, I believe, those are implemented in a pdf as /Annots, too)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Haven't tested it a great deal, but the following seems to work. It deletes all annotations, *except* internal document links (which none of the answers here seem to do). This script depends on the [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) python library.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, pdfrw

try:
    in_path = sys.argv[1]
    out = sys.argv[2]
except:
    print("Usage:\tannotclean IN.pdf OUT.pdf")
    exit(0)

reader = pdfrw.PdfReader(in_path)

for p in reader.pages:
    if p.Annots:
        # See PDF reference, Sec. 12.5.6 for all annotation types
        p.Annots = [a for a in p.Annots if a.Subtype == "/Link"]

pdfrw.PdfWriter(out, trailer=reader).write()
```

**Usage:**

1. Save as a script somewhere (I assume in your `PATH`), e.g. `/usr/local/bin/annotclean`.
2. `annotclean in.pdf cleaned.pdf`
3. (optional) batch processing:

```fish
# fish shell syntax
for p in **pdf # pdfs from current directory and subdirectories
    annotclean $p $p.new
    mv $p.new $p # overwrite the old
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I **think** you can do that most easily by "refrying" the PDF. Refrying means: first convert the file to PostScript, then convert the PostScript back to PDF. Usually refrying is frowned upon, because usually you loose quality and some content. In your case you *want* to loose the content. The re-frying can be done with [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/) (and the helper batch files shipping with it -- download the `gs900w32.exe` if you are on Windows), so here you go, with 2 easy commands:

```
pdf2ps.bat input.pdf output.ps
ps2pdf.bat output.ps input_refried.pdf
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Written-in comments remain (not as comments, but as part of the pdf).

Comment: If the comments are actually added to the content of the PDF, they can only be removed manually.  Actual PDF annotations are separate.

Comment: Is there any way without using any converter?

Comment: This also removes internal document links.

Comment: @AlecJacobson: Of course. If you convert to PostScript you loose a lot of the "rich" content that was part of PDF. PostScript does not have the means to represent ANY links, not even internal document links....

Answer (score 2):

OK, you said you'd also consider a commercial solution....

I'd recommend you try [**callas pdfToolbox**](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:products:pdftoolbox4). It's available for Windows and Mac OS X. (They have a CLI for Linux as well, but you can only use pre-configured "profiles" with it. With the Windows GUI, you can create your custom profiles and re-use them with the Linux CLI, though.

The pdfToolbox has lots and lots and lots of way to manipulate and fix many, many individual PDF problems.

One of the "Fixups" is to remove all annotations.

You don't need to shell out any money to test it first; callas gives out 14days trial licenses for free.

Comment: It indeed does have a way to to remove all annotations, but I'm not sure how to do a batch job.

Comment: Dunno about previous versions --- but the latest pdfToolbox5 release allows to run it in batch mode against complete folders containing PDFs.....

Answer (score 2):

A fast (in-memory) way is to use `pdftk` and `sed` as in the following shell pipeline:

```sh
pdftk in.pdf output - uncompress |\
 sed '/^\/Annots/d' |\
 pdftk - output out.pdf compress
```